# How to concat a string to a windows batch command variable in Jenkins?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I'm getting our application version value via curl command and set it into a `app_version` variable:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
  'curl myApp-installer:8080/info/version'
) do (
  set app_version=%%a
)
```

This works for me and I'm getting the value as expected.
Later on, I'm using this value as a parameter to build our application installer for overriding the application version.

My application version syntax should be: Beta - version %app_version%.
How can I concat the `app_version` variable to the "Beta - version" String?

Whatever I tried I got 2 strings like that: "Beta - version" "10.1.2"

Answer (score 0):

just set another variable called `beta_version`:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
  'curl myApp-installer:8080/info/version'
) do (
  set app_version=%%a
  set "beta_version=Beta - version %%a"
  set beta_version=%beta_version:"=%
  echo %beta_version%
)
```

or if you prefer:

```
set "beta_version=Beta - version %app_version%"
```

Comment: It still generating 2 string like this:
**Beta version "1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.1955"**.
It won't concat the 2 string into 1 string

Comment: I do not have access to your curl command. Does it actually generate the version with the double quotes?

Comment: Yes, it does get generate with double quotes. I mean - it's a GET method which returns a string, but the curl do return it with double quotes.

Comment: So then we just remove the double quotes, then `%beta_version%` becomes a single string.

Comment: Do you mean like this?
**set beta_version=Beta version %%a** because it still reproduce this: Beta version "1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.1955"

Comment: @user8874956 no, see edit in answer. `set beta_version=%beta_version:"=%` which will remove all double quotes from the actual string returned. and should actually then return `Beta -version 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.1955`

Comment: You have diagnosed the problem, but there is a much simpler solution with the `~` modifier. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47327738/1012053).

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - tnx but it still won't work... it will reproduce this:
("=)

Comment: @user8874956 Please copy my exact code and try again. It must work :)

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are actually literals within your variable values. You simply need to define the variables without the quotes in the value.

This is easily done when the value is coming from a FOR variable - you can use the `~` modifier. Enter `for /?` or `help for`, and then look at the bottom of the help output for a brief description of all available modifiers.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
  'curl myApp-installer:8080/info/version'
) do (
  set "app_version=%%~a"
)
```

Note that the quotes in my code above surround the entire assignment - structured like this, they do not get included in the value. This construct generally protects against poison characters, (not an issue when expanding FOR variables), and also prevents accidental trailing white-space characters from being included in the value - all characters after the last quote are ignored by the SET command.

Comment: Tnx, I tried it, but this line: **set "app_version=%%~a"** will delete the variable value completely and not just the double quotes.

Comment: @user8874956 - There must be more to the story. If `%%a` contains `"some value"`, then `%%~a` will yield `some value`. The only way for `%%~a` to yield an empty string is if `%%a` is empty, or if it contains only `""`. So either `%%a` doesn't contain what you think it does, or else some other part of your code is losing the value.